# Considering multiple events

Tags: c#

I have a C# application which uses multiple event handlers which are triggered by various events. As an example:

1. Global mouse hook event
2. Global Key hook event which is filtered (the handler only triggers with certain keypresses)
3. Active window change global hook
4. Structure Changed application hook (this is an UIAAutomation event where different structure changed event/handlers are created for each application window when it becomes the active window (so, for example, if the application is Internet Explorer then paging down the browser, clicking on another website link are examples of the structure changing on the Internet Explorer application instance)

All these events (running on background threads, e.g. MTA) have the effect of updating the UI window of my application. All of them are working as they should.

My issue is that with certain circumstances multiple events are triggered at the same time. So for example it is feasible that the following events are all triggered within 1 second (such a scenario would occur if I clicked on a different active window):

1. Global Change of active window
2. Global Mouse Hook
3. Application structure changed.

In different circumstances (e.g. different active applications) one event is preferred above the other as the defining event which is ruled by a set of conditions (Booleans) . I do not want to act on more than 1 event at a particular period of time.

What is the best programming mechanism for considering the events triggered and deciding, by a set of conditions, which one to act on? Of course this all has to be done within a very quick period of time (e.g. one second or less). The events if triggered will all occur within this period of time.

I hope this makes sense and if not please ask for clarification. Incidentally the reason I would like to update my UI of my application by a certain defining event is that the information that my UI presents will be slightly different depending on which event is fired (mainly due to the slight difference in timing when the differing events are triggered). Incidentally the time taken to trigger a particular event will vary depending on the action taken (e.g. clicking on a different active window). Sometimes one event type is quicker than another but then in different circumstances a different event type can be the quickest event (or the slowest event triggered)

Thank you for both the answers below very much appreciated. I will check out the System.Reactive library in the first place as it sounds purpose-built for the task.

Comment: [Rx](http://reactivex.io/) should help with that, but be prepared for a rather steep learning curve.

Comment: When an event arrives, start the timer if it's not started, and put the event information in a queue. When the timer ticks, pull all the events from the queue, and decide on which one you want to act

Comment: Have you tried to pipe all the events through one handler which either passes the event through to the current handler or revokes it depending on your rules?

Comment: Can you point me to an example that pipes all the events through one handler? This is a new concept to me.

Comment: I have a potential solution for you @user1956310, writing up an answer now.

Comment: @Scocia888 - If you could provide a [mcve] I could provide actual code on how to consume the events with Rx.

Comment: @Enigmativity how do I get the minimal example to you for you to produce actual code?

Comment: @Scocia888 - Show us the code that sets up the objects you are watching and the associated events so that we can, at the very least, compile and run your code. If possible make the code fire the events so that we can see actual values. If you can't do exactly that then create substitute classes that mimics your real code so that any answer we give you can translate back to your actual classes. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Scocia888 - The code I posted in my answer isn't your code, but it can be run and shows what can be done. If I had your code as a starting point I couldn't have written my code to use yours to start with and then you might be able to copy and paste mine to see it work in yours.

Comment: @Enigmativity understood but how do I give you access to the simple project I will create. This project is runnable and triggers with a couple of events.

Comment: @Scocia888 - You don't You put all of the code in the question that I can copy and paste into a project for myself. You need to make the code simple enough for the cope-paste to work.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's Reactive Framework (NuGet "System.Reactive") can do this kind of ting superbly and very powerfully. You can do some things very simply, but some queries - especially those dealing with time - can be quite complicated.

Here's a sample of what you might do:

```
var event1 = new Subject<int>();
var event2 = new Subject<int>();

var query =
    event1.Merge(event2).Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));

query.Subscribe(xs => Console.WriteLine($"\"{String.Join(", ", xs)}\""));

event1.OnNext(42);
Thread.Sleep(3000);
event2.OnNext(43);
Thread.Sleep(500);
event1.OnNext(44);
```

That outputs:

```
"42"
""
""
"43, 44"
""
""
```

Note that it produces the `"43, 44"` at the same time even though the events fire 500ms apart.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using code like below to prevent conflicts in event handling :

```
   class Program
    {
        enum EVENTS
        {
            EVENT1,
            EVENT2,
            EVENT3,
            EVENT4,

        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }
        static void EventHandler(EVENTS myEvent)
        {
                Object thisLock = new Object();

                lock (thisLock)
                {
                    switch (myEvent)
                    {
                        case EVENTS.EVENT1 :
                            break;
                        case EVENTS.EVENT2:
                            break;
                        case EVENTS.EVENT3:
                            break;
                        case EVENTS.EVENT4:
                            break;
                    }
                }
        }

    }
```

Comment: How does this prevent conflicts in event handling?

Comment: The lock only allows one event to go through code.  So if two events are using the same resource only one can access the resource at a time.

Comment: OK, so this only helps if two events fire almost simultaneously on different threads.

Comment: You can modify the code to allow one event to pause another event to give precedence.  What I like is it puts all the critical code in one method so it is easy to synchronize events rather than scatter code over may modules. .

Comment: That sounds good, but it's not what the OP is after. He wants to manage events that could be separated as much as 1 second apart.

Comment: In a real time system you normally run until complete unless a higher priority event occurs.  So you need semaphores to pause one event while a higher one runs.  Still the code that controls the semaphores can be put into the module.

Comment: Thank you both very much for your answers. I will check out the System.Reactive namespace in the first place as it sounds purpose-built for the task.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified version of my code with several global hooks which are triggered by change of active window and a left mouse click. If you left click on a different active window both the mouse click event and change of active window event will be triggered. If you could show me example code of using the Reactive namespace to deal with the 2 events when they are triggered within milliseconds of each other I would greatly appreciate it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Testing_multiple_events
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int activeWindowCount = 1;
        int activeMouseClickCount = 1;
        public Form1()
        {                
            InitializeComponent();
            // set up the global hook event for change of active window
            GlobalEventHook.Start();               
            GlobalEventHook.WinEventActive += new EventHandler(GlobalEventHook_WinEventActive);                        

            // Setup global mouse hook to react to mouse clicks under certain conditions, see event handler
            MouseHook.Start();
            MouseHook.MouseAction += new EventHandler(MouseHook_MouseAction);
        }

        private void GlobalEventHook_WinEventActive(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText("Active Window Change Global Hook Triggered: " + activeWindowCount + "\r\n");
            activeWindowCount++;
        }    

        private void MouseHook_MouseAction(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText("Global MouseHook Triggered: " + activeMouseClickCount + "\r\n");
            activeMouseClickCount++;
        }
    }
}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Testing_multiple_events
{
    public static class GlobalEventHook
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        internal static extern IntPtr SetWinEventHook(uint eventMin, uint eventMax, IntPtr hmodWinEventProc,
            WinEventDelegate lpfnWinEventProc, uint idProcess, uint idThread, uint dwFlags);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        internal static extern bool UnhookWinEvent(IntPtr hWinEventHook);

        public static event EventHandler WinEventActive = delegate { };
        public static event EventHandler WinEventContentScrolled = delegate { };

        public delegate void WinEventDelegate(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType, IntPtr hwnd, int idObject,
            int idChild, uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime);

        private static WinEventDelegate dele = null;
        private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;



        public static void Start()
        {
            dele = new WinEventDelegate(WinEventProc);
            _hookID = SetWinEventHook(Win32API.EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, Win32API.EVENT_OBJECT_CONTENTSCROLLED, IntPtr.Zero, dele, 0, 0, Win32API.WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT);
        }

        public static void stop()
        {
            UnhookWinEvent(_hookID);
        }

        public static void restart()
        {

            _hookID = SetWinEventHook(Win32API.EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, Win32API.EVENT_OBJECT_CONTENTSCROLLED, IntPtr.Zero, dele, 0, 0, Win32API.WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT);
        }

        public static void WinEventProc(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType, IntPtr hwnd, int idObject, int idChild, uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime)
        {

                if (eventType == Win32API.EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND)
                {                       
                    WinEventActive(null, new EventArgs());
                }
        }
}
}

    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Testing_multiple_events
{
    public static class MouseHook
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook,
          LowLevelMouseProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode,
          IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

        public static event EventHandler MouseAction = delegate { };

        private const int WH_MOUSE_LL = 14;

        private enum MouseMessages
        {
            WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201,
            WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202,
            WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200,
            WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A,
            WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x0204,
            WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x0205
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct POINT
        {
            public int x;
            public int y;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct MSLLHOOKSTRUCT
        {
            public POINT pt;
            public uint mouseData;
            public uint flags;
            public uint time;
            public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
        }

        public static void Start()
        {
            _hookID = SetHook(_proc);

        }
        public static void stop()
        {
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
        }

        private static LowLevelMouseProc _proc = HookCallback;
        private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;

        private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelMouseProc proc)
        {
            using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
            using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
            {
                IntPtr hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, proc, GetModuleHandle("user32"), 0);
                if (hook == IntPtr.Zero) throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception();
                return hook;
            }
        }

        private delegate IntPtr LowLevelMouseProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        private static IntPtr HookCallback(
          int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            if (nCode >= 0 && (MouseMessages.WM_LBUTTONDOWN == (MouseMessages)wParam || MouseMessages.WM_RBUTTONDOWN == (MouseMessages)wParam || 
                MouseMessages.WM_MOUSEWHEEL == (MouseMessages)wParam))
            {
                MSLLHOOKSTRUCT hookStruct = (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MSLLHOOKSTRUCT));
                MouseAction(null, new EventArgs());
            }
            return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }

    }
}
```